# extract mp3 from video file and use specific frame as cover image

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to convert some music videos to mp3 using ffmpeg.

How can I add a cover image from a specific part of the video (maybe by giving a minute and (decimal?)second) ?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a -vf trim=start='MM\:SS.mmm',trim=end_frame=1,setpts=0,scale=320:-1 -c:v:0 mjpeg -disposition:0 attached_pic out.mp3
```

where `MM\:SS.mmm` represents the time stamp of the image; (Colons should be escaped).

You don't usually to need to store a full-sized frame so I've added a scale filter.

Comment: hmm - it seems to work somehow - winamp shows the cover in the title informations - but the windows (7) file preview does not show the image. and also the mp3 player only on some converted videos shows them.